# Update DNS record in route53 using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

While trying to update a dns record in R53 using boto i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testing.py", line 106, in <module>
updateDns(load_balancer_dns)
File "testing.py", line 102, in updateDns
change.commit()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/route53/record.py", line 149, in commit
return self.connection.change_rrsets(self.hosted_zone_id, self.to_xml())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/route53/connection.py", line 320, in change_rrsets
body)
boto.route53.exception.DNSServerError: DNSServerError: 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

The following is the function i use to update the dns entry:

```
def updateDns(load_balancer_dns):
    r53 = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id=<access_key>,aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>)
    zone_id = r53.get_hosted_zone_by_name(<domain_name>)
    print zone_id
    change = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53,hosted_zone_id=zone_id)
    change.add_change_record("UPSERT", boto.route53.record.Record(name=<name>, type="CNAME", resource_records=load_balancer_dns, ttl=300))
    change.commit()
    print "record changed"
    return None

updateDns(load_balancer_dns)
```

Anyone else ran into such issues earlier ?

Comment: Try adding `debug=2` to your `boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection()` call. It will provide you with plenty of output to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since this doesn't truly have an authoritative answer here's a working script I have just cobbled together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from time import sleep

import boto


def main():
    """Entrypoint."""
    r53 = boto.connect_route53()
    zones = r53.get_all_hosted_zones()['ListHostedZonesResponse']['HostedZones']
    private_zone = find_private_zone('sub.mydomain.com.', zones)
    reverse_zone = find_private_zone('100.10.in-addr.arpa.', zones)

    upsert_record(r53, private_zone, 'dangus.sub.mydomain.com.', '127.0.0.1', 'A', wait=True)
    delete_record(r53, private_zone, 'dangus.sub.mydomain.com.', '127.0.0.1', 'A', wait=True)


def find_private_zone(name, zones):
    for zone in zones:
        if zone.get('Name') == name and zone.get('Config', {}).get('PrivateZone') in [True, 'true']:
            return zone

    return None


def find_record(r53, zone_id, name, record_type):
    records = r53.get_all_rrsets(zone_id)

    for record in records:
        if record.name == name and record.type == record_type:
            return record

    return None


def upsert_record(r53, zone, name, record, record_type, ttl=60, wait=False):
    print("Inserting record {}[{}] -> {}; TTL={}".format(name, record_type, record, ttl))
    recordset = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53, hosted_zone_id=zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1])
    recordset.add_change_record('UPSERT', boto.route53.record.Record(
        name=name,
        type=record_type,
        resource_records=[record],
        ttl=ttl
    ))
    changeset = recordset.commit()

    change_id = changeset['ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Id'].split('/')[-1]

    while wait:
        status = r53.get_change(change_id)['GetChangeResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Status']
        if status == 'INSYNC':
            break

        sleep(10)


def delete_record(r53, zone, name, record, record_type, wait=False):
    print("Deleting record {}[{}] -> {}".format(name, record_type, record))

    zone_id = zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1]
    record = find_record(r53, zone_id, name, record_type)

    if not record:
        print("No record exists.")
        return

    recordset = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53, hosted_zone_id=zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1])
    recordset.add_change_record('DELETE', record)
    changeset = recordset.commit()

    change_id = changeset['ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Id'].split('/')[-1]

    while wait:
        status = r53.get_change(change_id)['GetChangeResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Status']
        if status == 'INSYNC':
            break

        sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately, none of the APIs that I have worked with have a good Route 53 implementation and you eventually have to use these dictionary lookups to look into the XML actually returned by the service.

Some gotchas:

- Always use the FQDN which means every record should end with a dot.
- You can't just fetch the hosted zone you're looking for, you need to get all of them and search for the one that you're looking for (ie: a private zone matching the given name).
- You have to parse out the ID from your hosted zone.
- You have to parse out the ID from your change sets.
- When deleting entries, you must first capture the current state of the record if it exists at all, and then send that value to Route 53 as part of your deletion change.

This makes the API really aggravating to use, but at least it solves RFC-1925 rule number 1: it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166985/65706
    # courtesy of: Naftuli Kay

    #

    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
    from time import sleep

    import argparse
    import boto
    import pprint
    import sys

    def set_vars():
        usage_examples = '''
            clear ; poetry run python process_dns.py --action upsert --dns-zone cgfinics.com --dns-name dev.cgfinics.com --dns-value 168.10.172.10 --record-type A
            clear ; poetry run python process_dns.py --action upsert --dns-zone cgfinics.com --dns-name www.dev.cgfinics.com --dns-value  www.dev.cgfinics.com --record-type CNAME
            clear ; poetry run python process_dns.py --action delete --dns-zone cgfinics.com --dns-name dev.cgfinics.com
        '''
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('A quick and dirty DNS upsert to aws with boto \n\n' + usage_examples)
        parser.add_argument('--action', required=True, nargs='?',
            help="The action to perform - upsert or delete ")
        parser.add_argument('--dns-zone', required=True, nargs='?',
            help="The DNS zone to process ")
        parser.add_argument('--dns-name', required=True, nargs='?',
            help="The DNS name to process ")
        parser.add_argument('--dns-value', required=False, nargs='?',
            help="The DNS value to process ")
        parser.add_argument('--record-type', required=True, nargs='?',
            help="The DNS record type - could be A, CNAME ")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args


    def main():
        """Entrypoint."""
        args = set_vars()
        action = args.action
        r53 = boto.connect_route53()
        zones = r53.get_all_hosted_zones()['ListHostedZonesResponse']['HostedZones']
        dns_zone = args.dns_zone + '.' if not args.dns_zone.endswith('.') else args.dns_zone
        public_zone = find_public_zone(dns_zone , zones)
        dns_name = args.dns_name + '.' if not args.dns_name.endswith('.') else args.dns_name
        dns_value = args.dns_value
        record_type = args.record_type

        if action == "upsert":
            upsert_record(r53, public_zone, dns_name, dns_value, record_type, wait=True)
            sys.exit(0)

        if action == "delete":
            delete_record(r53, public_zone, dns_name, dns_value, record_type, wait=True)
            sys.exit(0)

        print("only the upser and delete actions are supported !!!")
        sys.exit(1)


    def find_public_zone(name, zones):
        for zone in zones:
            if zone.get('Name') == name and zone.get('Config', {}).get('PrivateZone') in [True, 'false']:
                return zone

        return None


    def find_record(r53, zone_id, name, record_type):
        records = r53.get_all_rrsets(zone_id)

        for record in records:
            if record.name == name and record.type == record_type:
                return record

        return None


    def upsert_record(r53, zone, name, record, record_type, ttl=60, wait=False):
        print("Inserting record {}[{}] -> {}; TTL={}".format(name, record_type, record, ttl))
        recordset = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53, hosted_zone_id=zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1])
        recordset.add_change_record('UPSERT', boto.route53.record.Record(
            name=name,
            type=record_type,
            resource_records=[record],
            ttl=ttl
        ))
        changeset = recordset.commit()

        change_id = changeset['ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Id'].split('/')[-1]

        while wait:
            status = r53.get_change(change_id)['GetChangeResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Status']
            if status == 'INSYNC':
                break

            sleep(6)


    def delete_record(r53, zone, name, record, record_type, wait=False):
        print("Deleting record {}[{}] -> {}".format(name, record_type, record))

        zone_id = zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1]
        record = find_record(r53, zone_id, name, record_type)

        if not record:
            print("No record exists.")
            return

        recordset = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53, hosted_zone_id=zone.get('Id').split('/')[-1])
        recordset.add_change_record('DELETE', record)
        changeset = recordset.commit()

        change_id = changeset['ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Id'].split('/')[-1]

        while wait:
            status = r53.get_change(change_id)['GetChangeResponse']['ChangeInfo']['Status']
            if status == 'INSYNC':
                break

            sleep(10)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue to this, so as a "debug" exercise, I did a

```
print zone_id
```

I noticed that the object was a dict / JSON response, so I changed my code to

```
zone_id = self.r53.get_hosted_zone_by_name(self.domain).get("GetHostedZoneResponse").get("HostedZone").get("Id")
```

And this seemed to work for me - I am now getting a 403, but that at least should be easier to fix.

Disclaimer - new to Python, so not sure if this is actually the right way!

Answer (score 0):

just for reference:

get the change_id, and then check the status with the boto connection (conn) until is says "INSYNC"

e.g.

```
 def updateDns(load_balancer_dns):
    r53 = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id=<access_key>,aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>)
    zone_id = r53.get_hosted_zone_by_name(<domain_name>)
    print zone_id
    change = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(connection=r53,hosted_zone_id=zone_id)
    change.add_change_record("UPSERT", boto.route53.record.Record(name=<name>, type="CNAME", resource_records=load_balancer_dns, ttl=300))
    _changes = change.commit()

    change_id = _changes["ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse"]["ChangeInfo"]["Id"].split("/")[-1]

    while True:
        status = r53.get_change(change_id)["GetChangeResponse"]["ChangeInfo"]["Status"]
        if status == "INSYNC": break
        sleep(10)
```